# How to remove dot points from label/category list in blogger?

Tags: list, label, blogger, point

I have unsuccessfully tried to remove the dot points on label list in footer of my blog. I have tried adding `.sect-left {list-style:none}`in css. What can I do to make it work?

Link to blog is: http://www.christianevidence.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need you use "list-style-type: none;" instead of "list-style: none;"
your code will be

```
.sect-left{list-style-type: none;}
```